# Credentials url-injection works in Chrome, for Firefox it returns 401

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, url, firefox

I do not have control over the app. Looking for a solution that doesn't involve changing it.

Standard injection
https://usr:pwd@auth.app/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=somecallback-link&scope=openid%20api
Works in chrome (kind of, it goes to blank page and after refresh it proceeds). Same auth request returns 303.

I've already changed `network.http.phishy-userpass-length` in firefox config.